# How can I make only a single shot on Delonghi EC9?

Tags: espresso-machine

I have a Delonghi EC9 and I want to make only a single shot. But, when I put the half amount of coffee in the portafilter the cup don't brew well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are low-end machines. Sometimes they do not ship them with a single shot portafilter to keep the costs low. If this is your case, means, if you don't have a single size portafilter you cannot make a single shot. See the differences on this post:

- [How should I manage settings for single shot / double shot](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/4345/how-should-i-manage-settings-for-single-shot-double-shot/4352#4352)

My humble advise is, get used to drinking doppios. :)

Comment: Can i buy a single shot porta filter?

Comment: It may be possible. But portafilters do not have standard sizes. Please check here: https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3800/what-effect-does-portafilter-diameter-have-on-espresso/3801#3801